SQL Connection Timeout Even though there are less than 100 connections in the POOL
I am using the rest service connecting to the SQL server for data read and write operations. I have this SQL job running to kill sleeping connections when I execute sp_who or sp_who2. I still get into this issue with the following exception Timeout expired.
**The timeout period elapsed before obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached. **
Still, I got this error, and when I executed sp_who it only had 5 sleeping connections.
I have a script that I run to kill the sleeping connections and I am making sure I close all my connections even if there is an exception
DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = 75 SELECT TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
GO

DECLARE @Spid INT
DECLARE @ExecSQL VARCHAR(255)
 
DECLARE KillCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR

    SELECT  DISTINCT SPID
FROM    MASTER..SysProcesses
WHERE   DBID = DB_ID('DatabaseName') and hostname='ServerName'  and  loginame='UserName' 
and last_batch <  DATEADD(mi,-5,GETDATE())
 
OPEN    KillCursor
 
-- Grab the first SPID
FETCH   NEXT
FROM    KillCursor
INTO    @Spid
 
WHILE   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET     @ExecSQL = 'KILL ' + CAST(@Spid AS VARCHAR(50))
 
        EXEC    (@ExecSQL)
 
        -- Pull the next SPID
        FETCH   NEXT 
        FROM    KillCursor 
        INTO    @Spid  
    END
 
CLOSE   KillCursor
 
DEALLOCATE  KillCursor


Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

SQL 2014 Standard Edition (64-bit)

What does your database connection code look like in your ASP.NET app?
